# Как указать var() в качестве значения одного из параметров (initial-value) @property для другого var()

Tags: css, css3, variable, css-variables

Сидел значит, тренировался в css с новыми фишками.
И уткнулся в проблему!
Есть у меня 2 переменные:

```
--number: 0;
--time: 30;
```

Так вот для `--time` нужно задать пропсы

```
@property --number {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: var(--time);
}
```

Вот только не задача, если `initial-value` установить статически, те же 30 например, то все работает как надо, но если вместо числа задать переменную, то тут уже не работает. Пробовал костыль типа `calc(var(--time) * 1)`, но нет, это так же не работает.
Как и почему?! Есть идеи?

Comment: Я похоже, что понял в чём дело, переменная в принципе не может указываться в `initial-value`, т.к. он сам должен быть статический, а вот переменные всегда динамические и также они зависят от родительских элементов, в которых можно поменять их (переменных) значения.

Comment: это вы нашли в документации или догадались?

Comment: 1) Догадался (Но это не правильное предположение) 2) Пишу сейчас ответ, весь ответ основан на документации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с самого начала, что такое `initial-value`?

[Из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property/initial-value):

> The `initial-value` CSS descriptor is required when using the `@property` at-rule unless the syntax accepts any valid token stream. It sets the initial-value for the property.
>
> The value chosen as the `initial-value` must parse correctly according to the syntax definition. Therefore, if syntax is `<color>` then the initial-value must be a valid `color` value.

Перевод:

> `initial-value` это CSS дескриптор, который требуется при использовании `@property` at-rule, только если синтаксис допусткает любой валидный (правильный) поток токенов. Оно назначает начальное значение для свойства.
>
> Значение выбранное для `initial-value` должно быть пропарсено в соответствии с определением синтаксиса. То есть, если синтаксис - `<color>`, значит начальное значение должно быть валидным (правильным) `color` (цветовым) значением.

То есть, если допустим мы введём `<integer>` для синтаксиса, то тогда `initial-value` должно быть типа `<integer>` (Пример: `10`, `42` и т.п.), соответственно оно не может быть `42px`, `#c0ffee`, `'foo'` или чем то, что не целое число. Согласны? Продолжаем.

Теперь, что такое `var()`?

[Из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/var):

> Функция CSS `var()` используется для вставки значения кастомного свойства (также известного как "CSS-переменная") в другое свойство.

Как мы видим в представленном примере из MDN, синтаксис (тип) у функции `var()`, это `<var()>`:

```
<var()> = 
  var( <custom-property-name> , <declaration-value> )
```

Уже догадались? То есть, сама по себе функция `var()` имеет тип `<var()>`, соответственно, если в `initial-value` передать `var(...)`, то сам `initial-value` будет типа `<var()>`, а как мы помним, если тип `inital-value` не совпадает с `syntax`, значит оператор `@property` не корректный. Бинго! Мы поняли в чём проблема :)

Теперь когда мы поняли что нужно вводить, пишем соответствующий код:

```css
@property --number {
  syntax: "<var()>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: var(--time);
}
```

Но так как `<var()>` может быть чем угодно, это лишает смысла весь код.

Материал по теме:

- [Переменные (--*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/--*)
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/var)
- [Использование переменных в CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)
- [At-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule)
- [`@property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property)
- [`initial-value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property/initial-value)

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо! Надеюсь все кто с этим столкнуться, увидят сперва этот ответ!

Comment: @JavierPena не за что! Рад, что мой ответ достаточно понятный :)